# Remove an object from ArrayList in another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `Project`class, which contains non-static ArrayList of `Issue` object

```
public class Project{

    private ArrayList<Issue> issue_Array = new ArrayList<>(); 

    //method to remove Issue
    public void removeIssue(Issue issue_obj) {
        this.issue_Array.remove(issue_obj);
    }

}
```

And here's the `Issue` class

```
public class Issue {

    public void deleteThisIssue() {
          Project.removeIssue(this);     //this is where I don't know
    }

}
```

I was finding a way for the Issue object to remove itself from its ArrayList in another class. My approach is to call the `removeIssue()` method from the `Project` class and pass `this`. But then I realize I can't declare `ArrayList<Issue>` as static since different `Project` stores different `ArrayList<Issue>`, how am I able to remove the Issue itself from its ArrayList stored in another class?

Comment: removeIssue is an instance method, it has to be called through an instance of Project, yet you are calling it as if it is a static method

Comment: Yes, I initially declared ArrayList<Issue> and removeIssue as static , but now I need ArrayList<Issue> and removeIssue to be as non-static now.

Comment: your removeIssue method should not be in the Issue class, it should be in the Project class, let's start with that. It makes no sense to have it in the Issue class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Issue {
    private Project project;
    public void deleteThisIssue() {
          this.project.removeIssue(this);     //do like this
    }
    public void setProject(Project project){
      this.project = project;
    }
}
```

At the place where you add issues to a project, inject issue with that project by invoking setProject() on Issue object.

Comment: so you first add the Issue to the project, so you can then add the Project to the Issue ... very poor design